# Symbology for multiple attributes within the same feature class in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, legend

How to represent two variables in one graduate symbol "figure", colors and graduate size circles[image].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use 'Multiple Attributes' under the symbology options in Layer Properties:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]